# Rails: Creating new posts in the other model's show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There are several locations and people can write posts about those locations. So what I did until now is that I created a table locations `(rails generate scaffold locations name:string)` and a table posts `(rails generate scaffold posts title:string text:string author:string image:string location_id:integer)`. So the Table `posts` has a foreign key to the table `locations`. So it's possible to view the posts in the show action of the table.

View for /locations/1 (show action of the location model) and View for /posts/new:

[image: View for /locations/1 (show action of the location model)][image]

What i want is that someone visiting one specific location can create a post without the need to fill the id-box as you can see below. It should automatically know that this post belongs to location with the current id. What do I have to change in the controller and what do I have to do in the html.erb-files so it works? I already tried this... but it retrieves a noMethod Error.

```
  def newpost
    @post = current_location.posts.build 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render json: @locations }
    end
  end
```

---

So I followed Charles' and Zajn's instructions.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
(...)
  def new
    #@post = Post.new
    @post = @location.posts.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end
(...)
end
```

in `config/routes.rb`

```
resources :locations do
  resources :posts
end
```

the posts-partial

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title, 'Title' %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.label :title, 'Text' %>
  <%= f.text_field :text%>

  <%= f.label :title, 'Author' %>
  <%= f.text_field :author %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :location_id %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

and there still seems to be an error:

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#new
```

details:

```
undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:28:in `new'

Request
Parameters:
{"location_id"=>"1"}

Response
Headers:
None
```

---

**second try:** Now I edited the `PostsController`

```
  def new
    #@post = Post.new
    @location = Location.find(params[:location_id]) # You can move this to a before_filter, if you prefer
    @post = @location.posts.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end
```

and it seems like there's no error in the controller anymore. Now there's some `NoMethodError`in the `html.erb`-files:

`undefined method 'posts_path' for #<#<Class:0x2404384>:0x204ed98>`

```
1: <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
2:     <%= f.label :title, 'Title' %>
3:     <%= f.text_field :title %>
4: 

app/views/posts/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_posts__form_html_erb___1061496502_7409780'
app/views/posts/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_posts_new_html_erb__238125222_5750540'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:31:in `new'
```

my `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title, 'Title' %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>

    <%= f.label :title, 'Text' %>
    <%= f.text_field :text%>

    <%= f.label :title, 'Author' %>
    <%= f.text_field :author %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :location_id, :value => @location.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

my `new.html.erb`

```
<h1>New post</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

I already tried to simply delete the last code `<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>`and it still retrieves the error, even I saved everything, shut down the server and reopened it. But I think the problem is not the posts_path. Because if I change the `<%= form_for @post do |f| %>`in the html.erb file into `<%= form_for @location.post do |f| %>`, it retrieves a `NoMethodError for 'post'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want posts to be a [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) under locations.

If that's what you're trying to do, then in `config/routes.rb`, you should have:

```
resources :locations do
  resources :posts
end
```

The url to create a new post for the location with id = 1 is `/locations/1/posts/new`, and your `new` action in `PostsController` should look like this:

```
def new
  @location = Location.find(params[:location_id]) # You can move this to a before_filter, if you prefer
  @post = @location.posts.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @post }
  end
end
```

Your `app/views/posts/_form.html.erb` partial should look like this:

```
<%= form_for [@location, @post] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title, 'Title' %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.label :title, 'Text' %>
  <%= f.text_field :text%>

  <%= f.label :title, 'Author' %>
  <%= f.text_field :author %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :location_id %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Note that, with nested resources, the route helpers that you use in your views are different.  For example, to get the path to the `index` action for the Posts belonging to a given location, you would use  `location_posts_path(@location)`, rather than `posts_path`.

Comment: wow! Thanks for this answer (and sorry for bad reply, but had no internet anymore), I get how it works. But somehow the `PostsController`still gives me a `no Method Error` with `undefined method `post' for nil:NilClass`. so I still might have done something wrong?

Comment: @Kirinriki, when is it hitting the `no method error`?  Is it in `PostsController.new` or another controller action?  If a different action, please edit your question to include that code.  It might also help to include your model code in the question.

Comment: @Kirinriki Sorry, I left out an important part for the controller!  You have to actually load the location.  See edited answer above.

Comment: thank you so much for your effort! Now there's no method error in the Controller anymore (or it just seems). Sadly, it gives out some `NoMethodError` in the html.erb files. I edited my question.

Comment: great. It works now! Thanks alot! I think I have to learn more about syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply add a hidden field that contains the id of the location to the form where you are creating the post.

So, something like this:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title, 'Title' %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>

    <%= f.label :title, 'Text' %>
    <%= f.text_field :text%>

    <%= f.label :title, 'Author' %>
    <%= f.text_field :author %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :location_id, :value => @location.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Where `@location` is an instance variable containing the current location that you're viewing.